# Ask about temperature analyzer program in c

Tags: c

Help me to find the highest and lowest temperature, please. I think I miss something to make it works. It is nearly done. Do I need to use if to create a condition?
Help me to find the highest and lowest temperature, please. I think I miss something to make it works. It is nearly done. Do I need to use if to create a condition?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMS 3

int main(void) {

int high;
int low;
int totalhigh=0;
int totallow=0;
double average;
int i;
printf("---=== Temperature Analyzer ===---\n");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
printf("Enter the high temperature for the day %d: ", i + 1);
scanf("%d", &high);
printf("Enter the low temperature for the day %d: ", i + 1);
scanf("%d", &low);
totalhigh = high + totalhigh;
totallow = low + totallow;
    }

average = (double)(totalhigh + totallow) / 6 ;
printf("The average (mean) temperature was: %.2lf\n", average);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int max = INT_MIN;` ... `if(max < high) max = high;`

Comment: Declare two variables: `min` initialized to `INT_MAX` and `max` initialized to `INT_MIN`, then check on each iteration if current value `< min` or `> max`

Comment: Unrelated to your questions, but since those three while loops all have identical code, why not just make one while loop with the three conditions or'd together?

Answer (score 1):

Not different from the comments which arrived while I was typing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMS 3

int main(void) {

    int high;
    int low;
    int highest =-42;
    int highday = -1;
    int lowday  = -1;
    int lowest  = 42;
    int totalhigh=0;
    int totallow=0;
    double average;
    int i;

    printf("---=== IPC Temperature Analyzer ===---\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the high value for day %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &high);
        printf("Enter the low  value for day %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &low);
        printf("\n");

        totalhigh = high + totalhigh;
        totallow = low + totallow;
        if (high>highest)
        {    highest=high;
             highday=i+1;
        }
        if (low<lowest)
        {   lowest=low;
            lowday=i+1;
        }
    }

    average = (double)(totalhigh + totallow) / 6 ;

    printf("The average (mean) temperature was:  %.2lf\n", average);
    printf("The lowest         temperature was: %3d on day %d\n", lowest, lowday);
    printf("The highest        temperature was: %3d on day %d\n", highest, highday);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Slightly different from comments, OK. I could not resist using 42. And I did not change the input error checking, feeling it would cloud the part which answers OPs question. I do agree however.

Comment: I rejected an edit on this answer, not taking the decision easily. The edit shortened the code (which is a good thing), by deleting the little error checking capabilities it has. The latter is what I do not like. Edits which replace, or better improve, the error checkers (by making them more efficient), are welcome. Deleting them outright is additional change (compared to OPs own code), which clouds the clarity of thosse changes which solve OPs question/problem. Even improving them is such "clouding" change, but improved and commented error checkers are a worthy goal and would be accepted.

Comment: Damn! I just noticed that the edit to my answer I rejected was in fact mirroring a change done to code in OPs question, **by OP**. Sorry, if I had noticed that detail when I was in review, I would have accepted. Ideas on how I can fix that are welcome.

Comment: I edited myself, doing the same thing I rejected, it is the best thing I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

You need to record the founded highest (as well as lowest).

```
struct hit
{
    int value,
        day;
};
struct hit highest = {-40; 0}, lowest = {+40; 0};
....
if (high > highest.value)
{
    highest.value = high;
    highest.day = i;
}
...
```

Finally you can print founded values:

```
print("The highest has been %d on day %d\n", highest.value, highest.day);
```

Comment: I think your output of days is off by one.

Comment: Loop is 0 to 2, days are counted 1 to 3, first input with i==0 for day 1. Printed question uses i+1. You store i and output without +1. Still seems off by one to me.